# Series of µsec pulse generation using Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due

I'm working on a project in which I need a series of very accurate pulses containing 2 shots in every pulse. The pulse should have 100µsec on time followed by 300ms off time. But when I'm programming the Arduino Due I'm getting random pulses of non-uniform width. But when I'm trying the same code in microsecond range I'm getting perfect wave.
Here is the code that I'm using

```cpp
#define LED 8 // Pin designated to give out the pulse
int cycles = 2;  // No. of times you want it to give pulse
int high = 100; // High time in microseconds
int low = 300;  // Low time in milliseconds
int i = 0;
int univ_cycle = 10;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
 Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop(){
  for (i ; i < univ_cycle; i ++){
  pulse();
  delay(100);
  }
}
void pulse() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  for(int counter = 0;counter < cycles;counter++){
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(high);
  Serial.println("ontime");
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  Serial.println("offtime");
  delay(low);
  Serial.println(counter);
  }

}
```

Here is the image of the waveform in microsecond setting 
[image]

Here is the wavefrom that we got in millisecond setting
[image]

I would like to know how can I get the similar wave in microsecond also.

Comment: I would suggest as a start removing those Serial.println calls. They will make complete nonsense of any timing you attempt to do.

Comment: Look into using one of the 16bit timers. What do you mean with “two shots in every pulse”?

Comment: @Gerben I assume he means `___-__-______-__-______-__-_____`

Comment: @Majenko silly me. I should have looked at the scope output.

Comment: @Gerben Can you please suggest me how to use 16-bit register?

Comment: Setup the timer to call an interrupt service routine every 100us. In this routine increment a counter. Set the output high when the counter is 0, and low otherwise. Reset the counter when you reach 3000 (i.e. 300ms). This is for a single pulse. For the double pulse you’d have to add some extra code. I’d suggest checking the timer1  library for setting up the timer interrupt.